# How to switch from funs to list in dplyr when the column name is used?

Tags: r, dplyr

I try to switch my code from **funs()** (package **dplyr**) to **list()**, especially in a **mutate_if()** function.

Unfortunately I have one piece of code that uses the column name as input parameter.
But when using the list() function the code breaks!

This example code simply replaces the content of the columns with the column name:

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)

atibble=tribble(~A, ~B,
                "A1", "B1",
                "A2", "B2")

print(atibble)

## A tibble: 2 x 2
#  A     B    
#  <chr> <chr>
#1 A1    B1   
#2 A2    B2   

atibble %>% 
  mutate_if(is.character, funs(quo_name(quo(.))))

## A tibble: 2 x 2
#  A     B    
#  <chr> <chr>
#1 A     B    
#2 A     B 

atibble %>% 
  mutate_if(is.character, list(~quo_name(quo(.))))

## A tibble: 2 x 2
#  A     B    
#  <chr> <chr>
#1 .     .    
#2 .     .
```

Not quite the same result. :-(

I tried a lot of combinations of quo, enquo, rlang::as_name, .., but nothing helped.

How can I fix the list() statement so that the code shows the same result as funs()?

My environment:

- Windows 10
- R version 3.6.1
- dplyr version 0.8.3

Thanks

EDIT: 
tmfmnk's solution works. I just want to show the whole problem here.
If somebody finds a solution without helper function I will be happy to see it. :-)

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

# my original problem involves dates.
btibble=tribble(~A, ~B,
                ymd("2019-11-04"), ymd("2019-10-20"),
                ymd("2018-02-12"), ymd("2019-02-06"))

# # A tibble: 2 x 2
#   A          B         
#   <date>     <date>    
# 1 2019-11-04 2019-10-20
# 2 2018-02-12 2019-02-06

# And I have a small function that I use.
# It determines the granularity I want for the date column.
getDateUnit <- function(x) {
  if (x == 'A') {
    return ("month")
  }
  return("year")
}

# works fine with funs.
btibble %>%
  mutate_if(is.Date, funs(floor_date(., getDateUnit(quo_name(quo(.))))))

# Column A is on the first of the month, column B is on the first of the year.
# # A tibble: 2 x 2
#   A          B         
#   <date>     <date>    
# 1 2019-11-01 2019-01-01
# 2 2018-02-01 2019-01-01

# does not work with list because the function call is getDateUnit('.').
# every column will be set to first day of year now
btibble %>%
  mutate_if(is.Date, list(~floor_date(., getDateUnit(quo_name(quo(.))))))

# Column A is not formatted by month, but by year.
# # A tibble: 2 x 2
#   A          B         
#   <date>     <date>    
# 1 2019-01-01 2019-01-01
# 2 2018-01-01 2019-01-01

# Throws error
btibble %>%
  mutate_if(is.Date, list(function(x) floor_date(x, getDateUnit(quo_name(enquo(x))))))

# Error: `expr` must quote a symbol, scalar, or call
# Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace. 

# The workaround I found was using a helper function that 
# does the computing in two steps:
helper_function <- function(x) {
  unit = getDateUnit(quo_name(enquo(x)))
  return(floor_date(x, unit))
}

# with the helper function both snippets below work.
btibble %>%
  mutate_if(is.Date, helper_function)

btibble %>%
  mutate_if(is.Date, list(helper_function))

# # A tibble: 2 x 2
#   A          B         
#   <date>     <date>    
# 1 2019-11-01 2019-01-01
# 2 2018-02-01 2019-01-01
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be no `.` inside the `list()` of functions:

```
atibble %>%
 mutate_if(is.character, list(function(x) quo_name(enquo(x))))

  A     B    
  <chr> <chr>
1 A     B    
2 A     B
```

Comment: Thanks! Your solution works for my reduced example.

Two notes here:

a) the ```.``` is normally OK in list, like here: ```atibble %>% mutate_if(is.character, list(~stringr::str_dup(., 2)))``` works fine.

b) it did not work in my original problem, but I found a workaround using your solution. I will edit my question and post both the original problem and my solution there.